# Lisp: Inspect function determine its required parameters

Tags: lisp, inspection

In Python, I can do this:

```
>>> def foo(x,y,z=1):
    return x+y*z

>>> foo.func_code.co_varnames
('x', 'y', 'z')
>>> foo.func_defaults
(1,)
```

And from it, know how many parameters I must have in order to call foo().  How can I do this in Common Lisp?

Comment: I suspect that this depends on the lisp variant/implementation.

Comment: Good point.  I edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most implementations provide a way of doing this, but none is standardized.  If you absolutely need it, Swank (the Common Lisp part of [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/)) has a function called `swank-backend:arglist` that, as far as I can see, does what you want:

```
CCL> (swank-backend:arglist 'if)
(TEST TRUE &OPTIONAL FALSE)
CCL> (swank-backend:arglist 'cons)
(X Y)
CCL> (swank-backend:arglist (lambda (a b c &rest args)))
(A B C &REST ARGS)
```

I'm not sure you can rely on it remaining available in the future, though.

Comment: This worked for me when using SLIME in emacs but not when I try to compile in gcl.  (require :swank-backend) isn't cutting it for me.  What'm I missing?

Comment: You need to install and load Swank before using its functions.  Unfortunately, I don't think Swank is available for GCL (which is a CL implementation generally not well supported nowadays anyway).  Is there a specific reason you're using it rather than, say, ECL (on which, by the way, you can use `si:function-lambda-list`)?

Comment: My pathetic newbness wasn't aware of the difference.  You've been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Usually most Lisps have a function called ARGLIST in some package. LispWorks calls it FUNCTION-LAMBDA-LIST.

For information purposes in LispWorks, if one has the cursor on a function symbol, then control-shift-a displays the arglist. In LispWorks there is also an 'arglist-on-space' functionality that can be loaded. After typing a symbol and a space, the IDE displays the arglist.

There is also the CL:DESCRIBE function. It describes various objects. In most CL implementations it also should display the arglist of a function.

The following example is for Clozure Common Lisp:

```
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.6-r14468M  (DarwinX8664)!
? (defun foo (x y &optional (z 1)) (+ x (* y z)))
FOO

? (arglist #'foo)
(X Y &OPTIONAL Z)
:ANALYSIS

? (describe #'foo)
#<Compiled-function FOO #x302000550F8F>
Name: FOO
Arglist (analysis): (X Y &OPTIONAL Z)
Bits: 8405508
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know this just when editing, SLIME+emacs will take care of that for you.

e.g. In emacs lisp-mode + slime, typing

`(format`

will display the arguments of format in the minibuffer on the bottom.